# System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException for inexistent mail address c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, smtp

I use the smtp for sending mail from my application , I want to catch the error when the mail address is valid but inexistent but the method didn't catch even i implement this code:

```
catch (System.Exception exp)
            {
                if (exp.GetType() == typeof(SmtpFailedRecipientException))
                {
                  //// display error message   
                 } 
}
```

What should i do?? Is SmtpFailedRecipientException didn't recognize inexistent address mail??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmtpFailedRecipientException` Represents the exception that is thrown when the `SmtpClient` is not able to complete a Send or SendAsync operation to a particular recipient.  [MS Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I assume it's an external SMTP client , so when sending  the mail
,it will not validate external mail address immediately. It is later after
the external node send back error message will it popup message sending
fail error. The SmtpClient component will close the communication with
server right after the message has been sent out, but not trace the
sequential message delivery status. [MS Answer](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/631019-smtpfailedrecipientexception-s-how-works)

In order to work fix your problem there are couple of things you can do :

- Try an external library [Here's a link for a good one](http://www.codicode.com/art/free_asp_net_email_validator_verifier.aspx)
- Create your own SMTP socket program [Here's another link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/check-if-email-address-really-exist-or-not-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: How could i use Asp.Net Email Validator? what is the dll that i will download?

Comment: It's a .net component (a dll file) the link i posted has a link to download it and you can import it to your environment and reference it in your app